# Installshield: Upgrade Windows Installer do not update anything?

Tags: installshield, updates

I have created an MSI installscript project in Installshield. I went to Project Assistant>Application Files, then added the application files(package) and built Setup.exe to install.

After installed these files, I went back to Project Assistant and added some application files, then i changed the product version for updating. Finally, i built the Setup.exe again. When i run the Setup.exe, the automatic update (Upgrade Window Installer Setup) asked me to update a new version. After finishing, I checked Program Files(x86) and the updating didn't do anything, the old package was still here.

How can i update my new package? Is there any way to disable the Upgrade Window Installer Setup?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion, most likely, you added new files to existing Component with keypath, which didn't change. Also you should check "Add\Remove Programs" snap-in in Control Panel to see if upgrade was applied - there should change version of your product.
So, I recommend you check Components, and re-allocate files to new Components if I had right. Also please read more about Components and Files. Could start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372830(v=vs.85).aspx).

Two words about InstallScript MSI project. From InstallShield documentation: *Because this project type uses two different engines, it is more complex than pure InstallScript or Basic MSI installation projects. It is recommended only for advanced users.*
So, if possible, use Basic MSI project - it's a bit simpler than InstallScript MSI for begginers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I recognize that I have to set up some configuration for the major upgrade. I have changed the productcode, package code and add a major upgrade in Upgrade Table. The upgrade work correctly.

Comment: Good to know it. Could you please then create answer and mark it as answered? Just to close this question.